# ASP.NET Core with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I have created a ASP.NET Core Web API application from the VS templates (I have updated VS with the latest ASP.NET Core RC2). However, I am running into issues when attempting to set up my application to use SimpleInjector as the IoC container.

I am using the instructions provided [here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html). When I have my mirroring the instructions found at that link, I get an error in the ConfigureServices method saying that IServiceCollection does not have a definition for AddInstance. It also says that IControllerActivator could not be found.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddInstance<IControllerActivator>(
        new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));
        services.AddInstance<IViewComponentInvokerFactory>(
            new SimpleInjectorViewComponentInvokerFactory(container));
    }
```

I realize there may be issues as I'm using the newest RC2 release of ASP.NET (and SimpleInjector support for ASP.NET Core is beta), but I was curious if anyone knew a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the imports?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have the stated using statements that are needed for SimpleInjector. That said, IServiceCollection looks like it is coming from the windows dependency injection assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making all the required parts of Simple Injector compatible with RC2 was quite some undertaking. Microsoft changed about everything (including API, MVC and tooling). So it took us a few days to fix this and create a compatible version.

But I'm happy to announce that v3.1.5 of Simple Injector is compatible with .NET Core 1.0.0-rc2 and version v3.1.5-rc2-02 of the SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNet package is compatible with RC2 as well. We updated [the documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore) as well.

Comment: Hi Steven. I'm still encountering issues unfortunately. I create a Core Web API from scratch, ran the command in the documentation to install SimpleInjector "Install-Package SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNet -Pre", but I'm still getting errors when I try to set up my app as in the documentation. I'm getting errors IControllerActivator and IViewComponentActivator cannot be found.

Comment: I did notice that `using SimpleInjector.Extensions.ExecutionContextScoping;` is not being used.

Comment: @Andrew: which version of the integration packafe did you pull in? Could be a Nuget caching issue.

Comment: Hey @Steven. Nuget says I have version 3.1.5-rc2-02

Comment: @Andrew That sounds right. Can you create an issue on Github and attach a sample project as zip that demonstrates the issue? I will look at it a.s.a.p.

Comment: @Andrew: Can you try again first with `3.1.5-rc2-03`?

Comment: Hi @Steven. I gave rc2-03 a try. Did not solve my issue, unfortunately. I have put a test project on git [here](https://github.com/atpsullivan/WebApplication1).

Comment: @Andrew: You should add the proper namespaces for `IControllerActivator` and `IViewComponentActivator`.

Comment: @Andrew: Please try the [latest NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNet) and take a look at the [updated documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore). This should resolve your trouble.

Comment: My original issue is now resolved, however, there is still an issue in the `InitializeContainer` method. In the documentation, it says to add components using `RegisterMvcControllers()` and `RegisterMvcViewComponents()` but those don't exist. Did you mean `RegisterAspNetControllers()` and `RegisterAspNetViewComponents()`

Comment: @Andrew This means you don't have the latest version.

Comment: Is there anything special I need to be doing to install these packages? Like, do I have to uninstall first? So far I've just been going to the Package Manager Console and typing `Install-Package SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNet -Pre`. Afterwards, it says `Successfully installed 'SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNet 3.1.5-rc2-07'`, and I consider that being updated.

Comment: When I cleaned, restarted, and rebuilt, it then showed rc2-02, not rc2-07. So, I uninstalled the package, cleaned, restarted, rebuilt, reinstalled and we're now good. Thanks Steven! I'll test making a simple web api service in the next couple days.

Comment: @Steven, I use `SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNet 3.1.5-rc2-07`, but why I still get error of `'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddInstance' and no extension method 'AddInstance' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SimpleInjectorCore..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 `

Comment: @Bigeyes: Please post a new question/issue here https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/new with all the relevant details.

Comment: @Steven Using the example in the documentation you linked when I'm in an action filter and use`context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUserRepository>()` it is null. When registering services with the Simple Injector Container how do we access them using the asp.net framework above?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan you don't. HttpContext.RequestServices is the list of framework registrations. To get a Simple Injector registration you query the Simple Injector container.

Comment: I don't know if it's already fixed but don't forget to use the ConfigureServices method that returns a new IServiceProvider. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#replacing-the-default-services-container so:

`public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

Comment: @JohnLandheer your comment assumes the use of an adapter for the Conforming Container which is something Simple Injector does *not* support. So there is no need for using that specific ConfigureServices signature.

Comment: @steven You are right (of course), I was too fast with my comment. Interesting read on their blog about how and why